# How to read all Google Policies? Is there any API Exposed by Google

Tags: html, google-chrome

Suppose we have url "https://policies.google.com/?hl=en-US" and I want to get Google policy updates real time to my. For that is there any Google API exist? Through which I can Pull data from policies.

Comment: Have you tried oEmbed components?

Comment: @painotpi - Can we use oEmbed with this URL https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-US ?

Answer (score 0):

create a custom safe pipe import it to your app module then in your component push the iframe source when it's ready and it should render it. Some websites have cross-origin error so maybe put sandbox attributes.

Component.ts

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url:any) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}

safeURL: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Component.html

```
<iframe  [src]="(safeURL | async | safe)"> </iframe>
```

Comment: We can't do this because we want to integrate third party URL and which has X-Frame-Options set to SameOrigin

Comment: unless you have access to the third party's server config you can't do much. Reason being that they send an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header as you said. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page. This is a security feature to prevent click-jacking.